# Subgraphs in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, nhibernate

I have 4 classes: Country, Prefecture, District and Cities, I have a requirement that whenever I persist a Country, that object generates all the necessary relationships with it.

Here is the code for the objects:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "countries")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
@NamedEntityGraph(name = "graph.prefectures", attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "prefectures"))

@NamedEntityGraph(
        name = "graph.CountryPrefectureDistrictCities",
        attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "prefectures", subgraph = "subgraph.prefectures"),
        subgraphs = {
                @NamedSubgraph(name = "subgraph.prefectures",
                        attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "district", subgraph = "subgraph.district")),
                @NamedSubgraph(name = "subgraph.district",
                        attributeNodes = @NamedAttributeNode(value = "cities"))
        })
public class Country implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long countryID;

    @Column(name = "CountryName")
    private String countryName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, mappedBy = "country", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Prefectures> prefectures = new HashSet();

    public Country() {
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "prefectures")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Prefectures implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long prefectureID;

    @Column(name = "PrefectureName")
    private String prefectureName;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, mappedBy = "prefectures", orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<District> district = new HashSet();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "countryID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Country country;

    public Prefectures() {
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "district")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class District implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JsonProperty("districtID")
    private Long districtID;

    @Column(name = "DistrictDescription")
    @JsonProperty("districtDescription")
    private String districtDescription;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH, mappedBy = "district", orphanRemoval = true)
    @JsonProperty("cities")
    private Set<City> cities = new HashSet();

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "PrefectureID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private Prefectures prefectures;

    public District() {
    }
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "city")
@Getter
@Setter
@AllArgsConstructor
public class City implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long cityID;

    @Column(name = "CityDescription")
    private String cityDescription;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "DistrictID", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    @JsonIgnore
    private District district;

    public City() {
    }
```

And this is the repository

```
@Repository
public interface CountryRepository extends JpaRepository<Country, Long>{

    @EntityGraph(value = "graph.CountryPrefectureDistrictCities", type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
    Optional<Country> findById(Long id);
}
```

My problem is that it doesn't recognize the attribute `cities` in the subquery of the Country's @NamedEntityGraph
[subgraph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fZ0en.png)

[Queries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BZsY4.png)

Comment: Have you tried executing the code? If so, what is the error?

Comment: Project runs, endpoint works but as you can see in the newly added image it spamms the database to fetch cities because it does not recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

The `NamedAttributeNode` value of `cities` is being recognized.

[image: Country.java]

The entity classes are in the same package, and I declared `org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa:2.5.5` as a dependency which transitively brings in `org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.32.Final`

Comment: I'm using this version of Spring Boot too...
`
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.5-SNAPSHOT</version> 
`
Intellij doesn't recognize cities even if I press ctrl+space, If I press ctrl+space at "district" attribute it gives me all the attributes inside this. I solved it by useing @Query at the moment but i'd like to know what's the problem with my implementation

Comment: @Ugleethyn - I was unable to find `2.5.5-SNAPSHOT`. the latest version is `2.5.5` at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot/2.5.5

https://spring.io/blog/2021/09/23/spring-boot-2-5-5-available-now